# m4:/etc/mail/sendmail.mc:176: cannot open '/usr/share/sendmail-cf/feature/'relay_hosts_only'.m4': No such file or directory

Tags: centos, sendmail

I've looked for an answer to this error all over, and I keep finding only the one people would get if sendmail-cf wasn't installed. Yes the file doesn't exist, but do I try to make it and with what content or do I just comment that line out? The install and config tutorial I used said to do `hostname >> /etc/mail/relay-domains` and then run `m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf` but when I run the m4 command I get the error in the title.

Comment: Note: accepting an answer is enough to indicate your problem is solved; there's no need to put "solved" in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m4` requires quotes quite unlike other programming languages.

```
dnl Sample of correct m4 quotes and common mistakes 
FEATURE(`relay_hosts_only') dnl OK
FEATURE('relay_hosts_only') dnl !!!BAD!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the above error, you must install the package sendmail-cf

`yum install sendmail-cf`